# Azure DevOps Server 2019 - Rules, make required attachments on state change

Tags: azure-devops, rules, azure-devops-server-2019, azure-devops-server

I'm new using Azure DevOps Server and i having some problems creating rules.
I'm trying to make a rule that doesn't allow the user to change the state of a Feature on the Board if this Feature doesn't have any attachment on it.

The rule i created is something like this:
[Test Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IGQl.png)
.
Right now with this rule it still permits the user to change state.

I practiced with other rules where i made required to have a description on state change and it worked fine not allowing the user to change state and showing "error" on the board.

I was testing with the querys if the feature I was using had any files attached but the result showed the work item correctly when i used that "Attached File Count" = 0.

If someone had some issue similar to this and can help me with it I'll apprecite it very much.

Comment: Hi,@Franco Maieli How is your problem progressing?Do you try the solution given by me?If you have any question,please kindly let me know.

Comment: Hi @HughLin-MSFT, sorry for not answering before. Your solution worked very well, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your rule setting doesn't work is that the default value of the `Attached File Count` is 0, so the Make required `Attached File Count` set in your Actions is not valid.

As a workaround ,you can achieve it through the following setting:

First, you can create a new field in the Feature item, as shown below.

[image]

Then we need to new two rules :

[image]

[image]

If you don't want the needAttachment field to be displayed in the work item page to prevent being manually modified, you can choose `Hide from layout` option.

[image]

After setting, when someone want to modify the state, if there is no attachment, he will get an error.

[image]

Comment: Works in Azure DevOps as well. Thx for the workaround.